# Return promise inside resolve function as its continuation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

#### Context

I'm working with Angular. I have a *service* called *UserService*, that handles login, authentication and user data requests.

The **get** method needs to check if the user has a valid (not expired) token for authentication before making the `get` request.
So, if it has, make the request, if not, request a token and **then** make the request.

#### Problem

This **get** method needs to hide its complex requests. It has to return only a Promise as it was making only one request.

So, an example of usage:

```
UserService
    .get()
    .then(data => { ... })
    .catch(error => { ... })
```

#### Wrong solution

Check if the token is expired. If it is, return a request to refresh the token, and there, make and return the get request. If it is not, just make and return the get request. As below:

```
function get() {
    if (isTokenExpired(token))
        return $http
            .post(url + '/refreshtoken', 'token=' + refreshToken)
            .then(response => {
                token = response.data.token
                return $http.get(url + '?token=' + token)
            })
            .catch(response => { ... })
    else
        return $http.get(url + '?token=' + token)
}
```

But it's returning a promise that I will have to handle like this:

```
UserService
    .get()
    .then(request => {
        request // THAT IS NOT GOOD
            .then(data => { ... })
            .catch(error => { ... })
    })
    .catch(error => { ... })
```

Anything like the usage example!

#### Correct solution

How to make this **get** method on service, which handles authentication like that and hides everything from the controller that will use, letting it like in the usage example?

Comment: How do you know in your Get response that your token is expired?

Comment: Did you actually try this code? I cannot believe that `request` is a promise in the `then` callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it's returning a promise for a promise that I will have to handle like this:
>
> ```
>  UserService.get().then(request => { request.then(data => { … }) })
> ```

**No.**

[Promises do chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572), any "promise for a promise" will implicitly be flattened to a promise for the inner result. Your "wrong solution" code simply works as is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. Basically you need to transform with an additional `.then()`

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .service('UserService', function($http) {
    let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

    function getUserData(token) {
      return $http.get(url + '/users/1', {
          token: token
        })
        .then(resp => resp.data);
    }

    this.get = function(tokenIsValid) {
      if (!tokenIsValid){
        console.log('refreshing');
        return $http.post(url + '/posts', {
            refreshToken: 'rt'
          })
          .then(getUserData)
        }
      return getUserData();
    }
    return this;
  })
  .run(function($rootScope, UserService) {
    $rootScope.get = (valid) => {
      console.log('Getting with ' + (valid? '':'in') + 'valid token');
      UserService.get(valid)
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <button ng-click="get()">Get invalid</button>
  <button ng-click="get(true)">Get valid</button>
</div>
```